# Run Fon on DD-WRT

Tags: dd-wrt

I'm using DD-WRT image in my Linksys router. Is it possible become Fon member with this router or I need to buy special Fon http://corp.fon.com/ router?

If it is possible, then how to setup my DD-WRT?

If no, what are alternative Internet sharing providers that might be supported by DD-WRT?

Comment: Yes, it appears that it was possible but I don't know if it is still. I refer you to this search ["fon hotspot on dd-wrt - Google Search"](http://www.google.com/search?q=fon+hotspot+on+dd-wrt).

Answer (score 0):

From the [FON site](http://corp.fon.com/how-it-works) it looks like you have to have their router. So I don't think it would be possible to use DD-WRT.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this, http://www.geek-pages.com/articles-for-geeks-mainmenu-2/1-latest/30-dd-wrt-multiple-ssids-1-for-fon-1-for-private-network

Or the long version http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/FON_Hotspot#FON_On_DD-WRT_w.2F_Chillispot

Comment: Welcome to SU! Please include an actual solution into your answer, instead of posting mere link. Thanks.